# how to get nook simple touch's device id?

Tags: android, adb, nook

To use the APK Downloader([link](http://codekiem.com/2012/02/24/apk-downloader/)),i have to know the nook's device id.
I hava used a app called device id,but the device id only has 15 characters(it should have 16 character).Then i try to use adb.like this:

```
adb devices
```

but it returns the serial-number what has been printed on the nook,it must not be the device id.
did somebody know how to get the nook simple touch's device id?

Comment: if you mean device id==IMEI number then there is no deviceID/IMEI number for nook its just an tablet not an phone. but you can have MAC add in that.

Comment: You can get it with this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.redphx.deviceid

Comment: The Device ID works,but it gives the device id which has only **15** characters.And it is illegal.I feel strange about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Nook Touch using ADB:

```
cat /rom/devconf/DeviceID
cat /rom/devconf/SerialNumber
```

Both return the same 16 digit number as printed on the SD card compartment.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a zero to the beginning of the 15 character ID from Device ID.